# Importing android app project from windows to Mac/ Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I developed an android application on windows and it works very fine! Also worked on my device (Samsung young), but when I imported it into Mac I faced a problem with launching it on Galaxy S3. May I refer that the codes are correct and there are no errors while installing it in the device, the problem is when it's running on the device it stops suddenly and a message appears "Unfortunately MySupermarket has stopped."

I need your help please, since I'm no advanced developer.

This is the LogCat:

```
05-05 14:18:57.245: D/AndroidRuntime(5615): Shutting down VM
05-05 14:18:57.245: W/dalvikvm(5615): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c30700)

05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysupermarket2/com.example.mysupermarket2.adwaa.mysupermarket2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mysupermarket2.adwaa.mysupermarket2.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.mysupermarket2-2.apk
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mysupermarket2.adwaa.mysupermarket2.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.mysupermarket2-2.apk
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
05-05 14:18:57.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5615):     ... 11 more
```

After doing the steps below the problem still exists, this is the LogCat after these steps:

```
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysupermarket2/com.example.mysupermarket2.adwaa.mysupermarket2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mysupermarket2.adwaa.mysupermarket2.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.mysupermarket2-1.apk
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mysupermarket2.adwaa.mysupermarket2.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.mysupermarket2-1.apk
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
05-05 15:17:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(8017):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I posted it, you can check it.

Comment: you got ClassNotFoundException, try to remove dependencies and clean your build and run again....

Comment: How can I do that ? will you show me the steps please ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this exception go to Eclipse, right click on Project properties. You will get properties pop up in that from the menu on the left click on Java Build Path and in the right side click on Order and Export tab. Inside that tab uncheck the Android Dependencies, after this just clean your build and run again.

Comment: I did this and yet the same problem exists! please check the logcat

Comment: From the same route? Java build path ?

Comment: java build path -> libraries